# Как передать правильно обработать событие keyup?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Хочу сохранять информацию, вводимую пользователем в форму. Что бы обновить ее при обновлении страницы.

Сохраняю в сессии.

Только если я ставлю событие на onkeyup, то JS отправляет каждую введенную букву.

Вопрос. А как сделать задержку в 2 сек. Что бы отправлять запрос после того, как пользователь прекратит вводить информацию?

Comment: событие `onchange` не подойдет?

Comment: Нет. Так как пользователь может писать текст и не выходить с формы.
А когда страница обновится или исчезнет интернет его вводимые данные пропадут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо чтобы отправило данные только если пользователь перестал вводить данные - то можно вот так:

```js
$('body').on('keyup', "#контейнер", function(I) {
  switch (I.keyCode) {
    default: searchDelay(function() {
      $.ajax({
        //ДЕЛАЕТЕ ВАШ ЗАПРОС
      });
    }, 1000);
    break;
  }
});

var searchDelay = (function() {
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо! Как раз то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше использовать onblur=ваша функция(), функция будет запускаться при потере фокуса на поле ввода.

Comment: Не подойдет. Так как пользователь может писать текст и не выходить с формы. А когда страница обновится или исчезнет интернет его вводимые данные пропадут.

Comment: @Anton Это то же не вариант, так как пользователь может закончить ввод но фокус может быть все еще в input

Comment: Тогда можно сделать задержку на 2-5 секунд, что если перестал вводить, то запустить функцию, для этого ознакомьтесь с SetTimeout(), очень удобно.

Comment: То есть после каждого ввода символа заходить в функцию и запускать таймер на 2-5 секунд, и по их истечению отправлять введенную строку.

Comment: @Anton, а не подскажите как это правильно сделать. А то у меня задержка срабатывает, но после 2 секунд все равно отправляет все символы без исключения

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам вообще хранить пользовательский вввод на сервере? Храните его у пользователя (в localStorage например). А на сервере сохраняйте штатным методом, когда пользователь захочет отправить форму на сервер.

Comment: Лучше на сервере. Так надежнее